# VLC player automatically closed on suspend - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, suspend, vlc

When my system is suspended, ubuntu `14.04` automatically closes all the open VLC players. I recently migrated to `14.04` from `12.04`, and I was not facing this problem with `12.04`. I normally have one or more vlc players open, and quite often I put my system to sleep/suspend. It seems now I cannot do that anymore.

Is this the default behaviour of `14.04` ? Everytime I suspend, I have to manually go and open the media files from the start and it is very frustrating. Is there a fix for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I switched to nvidia graphics driver (instead of default x-org driver) in system settings, the vlc no longer closes on suspend and the problem was fixed automatically.

Steps:

`System Settings -> Software & Updates -> select nvidia (or other proprietary drivers)`

For this, you need to install nvidia (or other proprietary drivers) in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with suspend after upgrading to 14.04. Upgrading to the latest mainline kernel fixed it.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14-trusty/

**For i386**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.0-031400_3.14.0-031400.201403310035_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.0-031400-generic_3.14.0-031400.201403310035_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14-trusty/linux-image-3.14.0-031400-generic_3.14.0-031400.201403310035_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If this does not fix it you could easily roll back to your old kernel by selecting on grub menu at boot time.